# AngularJS ng-init directive is assigned with function and promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, promise

I was trying to use promise from geocoder lattitude and langitude. that need to be trigger from the ng-init directive. but I was not able to use promise inside a function. [plunker for example](http://plnkr.co/edit/aFojLBNvszKIPmQIjGgC?p=preview) my ng-init look like this:

```
<div>Address {{ $index + 1 }}: {{ facility.address }}<span  ng-init="distance = maps(facility)" > distance = {{distance}}</span></div>
```

the whole code is inside a ng-repeat. since my codes are in ng-repeat i cannot use timeout. i think so span having ng-init is replaced with `{}` this. you can check that out in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aFojLBNvszKIPmQIjGgC?p=preview). I don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your plunker and in your `ng-init` you assign your variable `test` to the result of the function test1 which return itself a `Promise` and you can't directly print a `Promise` object in an angular template.

As `test` is a `Promise` object, so you can use `test.then(function (result) { /* ... */ })`.

Comment: you meant i should not use promise. instead of that suggesting me to use .then  >> am i correct

Comment: In your case you can avoid using a promise, so don't use it. And if you have to use a promise, you should think of using `$q`instead of `Promise`, or you will have to manually launch a digest in your `then` (ex: `$timeout()` etc). Take a look at : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: wow awesome $q is also not working i tried. so i think i had to use timeot

Comment: That's probably because you don't use $q properly. You can find examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/softwaredoug/z58vmdnn/ (that's not the promise itself that you can show in the template, but you can change the scope based on the results of a promise)